# Powershell custom object hidden property types

Tags: powershell, reflection

### Background:

I have a PSCustomObject that was created by converting a JSON array via `... | convertfrom-json`. The object has a lot of other objects for the property values (basically it's a collection of a lot of PSCustomObjects).
From knowing the object I know it contains at least three different types of objects (types meaning PSCustomObject with different properties).

### Issue:

When running Get-Member I only two object types and their members, the third one is not listed at all. I know there is a third object type as I can select properties that are only available in that object.

### Note:

I did have once a similar issue, where some members would only appear in the results of `get-member` only if called first in a `$object | select...` method, otherwise they just didn't show up. I didn't figure it out then either. The current issue is **not** the same but might be related, as I tried the method of `$object | select...` and it didn't help.

### Note2:

I did notice when trying to post code that is reproducible I get only one object type in return instead of two I get from the `invoke-restmethod`, this makes my question even bigger, what's going on here, why are some object types returned and some not.

### Example:

Example of get-member result

```bsh
$res.address_objects.ipv4 | gm       


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
host        NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject <snip>
name        NoteProperty string name=<snip>
uuid        NoteProperty string uuid=<snip>
zone        NoteProperty string zone=<snip>

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
name        NoteProperty string name=<snip>
network     NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject <snip>
uuid        NoteProperty string uuid=<snip>
```

As you can see there are two object types here and they both have some different property names.

### Sample:

#### Sample Json that I convert to an object.

Taken from @Jawad's answer.

Please note: This sample is not an exact copy of my code as my psobject is the result of a `invoke-restmethod` that automatically converts the json to an object.

```bsh
$json = @"
{
  "address_objects": {
    "ipv4": [{
        "host": "hostValue",
        "name": "hostName",
        "uuid": "value",
        "zone": "thisZone"
     },
     {
        "name": "NewName",
        "network": "newNetwork",
        "uuid": "thisUuid"
     },
     {
        "name": "NewName",
        "range": "newrange",
        "uuid": "thisUuid"
     }]
  }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json
```

#### Output I expected When running `Get-member`:

```bsh
$json.address_objects.ipv4 | gm       


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
host        NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject <snip>
name        NoteProperty string name=<snip>
uuid        NoteProperty string uuid=<snip>
zone        NoteProperty string zone=<snip>

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
name        NoteProperty string name=<snip>
network     NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject <snip>
uuid        NoteProperty string uuid=<snip>
   

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
name        NoteProperty string name=<snip>
range     NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject <snip>
uuid        NoteProperty string uuid=<snip>
```

Basically there is three distinct psCustomObjects so `get-member` should list them all three.

#### Edit #1:

Edited thanks to the commenter, they were right so I added a reproducible sample and clarified what I'm asking about. I haven't yet dissected in-depth the answers given.

Comment: `$json.address_objects.ipv4 | ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-Member  -MemberType Properties }` should do the job. However, the exhaustive explanation by @mklement0 is valid…

Comment: @JosefZ, your command will show a _single list_ of properties _with duplicates_, including for variations in _value_ (note that the input is "a collection of a lot of PSCustomObjects"), whereas the goal was to output a list of distinct property _sets_, i.e. to have one block of output per distinct "custom type" (as `Get-Member` does with truly distinct types). However, you can adapt your command to answer a _different_ question: `... | ForEach-Object { ($_ | Get-Member -MemberType Properties).Name } | Sort-Object -Unique` outputs the list of _distinct property names_ across all input objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) by design lists the *distinct* types among its input objects.<sup>[1]</sup>

However, **the problem with `[pscustomobject]` instances is that `Get-Member` does *not* recognize them as different types *even if they have differing properties***.

```bash
# Send 3 [pscustomobject] instances with distinct properties to Get-Member
[pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 },
[pscustomobject] @{ four = 4; five = 5 },
[pscustomobject] @{ six = 6; seven = 7 } | Get-Member
```

The following unexpectedly yields only a *single* output object, showing only the *first* `[pscustomobject]` instance's members:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
one         NoteProperty int one=1
three       NoteProperty int three=3
two         NoteProperty int two=2
```

**`Get-Member` distinguishes types only by their (full) *type names***, as reflected in the hidden instance property `.pstypenames`'s first element (**`.pstypenames[0]`**), *without considering a given instance's specific properties.*
That type name for `[pscustomobject]` instances is `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` by default.

Note that `.pstypenames[0]` by default contains the same type name as `.GetType().FullName`, but "made-up" names may be inserted<sup>[2]</sup>, which is what happens with `[pscustomobject]` instances created by the `Select-Object` cmdlet, for instance (see bottom section).

---

**Workaround**:

Note: The following works for *display* output (which should be fine, given that `Get-Member` output is usually used for *visual* inspection).

```
[pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 },
[pscustomobject] @{ four = 4; five = 5 },
[pscustomobject] @{ six = 6; seven = 7 } |
  Group-Object { "$($_.psobject.Properties.Name)" } | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Member -InputObject $_.Group[0] | Out-Host
  }
```

- [`Group-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) is used to group the input objects by their list of property names, using a calculated property (via a script block (`{ ... }`) that is evaluated for each input object).

  - `$_.psobject.Properties.Name` yields an array of all property names, and `"$(...)"` converts that into a space-separated list.
- Each group is then processed via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), passing each group's first instance (`$_.Group[0]`) directly  to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)

  - So as to ensure that individual `Get-Member` calls produce individual *display* output, [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) is used; without it, the display output would mistakenly suggest a *single* input type comprising the properties across *all* distinct types.

If you're only interested in the **list of distinct *property names*, across all input objects**:

```
# This yields the sorted array of all unique property names, across all
# input objects:
#     'five', 'four', 'one', 'seven', 'six', 'three', 'two'
[pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 },
[pscustomobject] @{ four = 4; five = 5 },
[pscustomobject] @{ six = 6; seven = 7 } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.Properties.Name } | Sort-Object -Unique
```

---

As for **your symptoms**:

Note that your first `Get-Member` output block mentions a *different* type name: `Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`

**The `Selected.` prefix implies that the object was created via the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet**.
While such an object is technically *also* a `[pscustomobject]` instance, the modified type name causes `Get-Member` to treat it as a different type.

Here's a simplified example:

```
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 }
$obj, ($obj | Select-Object -Property *) | Get-Member
```

This yields the following; note how the properties are the same and only the type name differs:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
one         NoteProperty int one=1
two         NoteProperty int two=2

   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
one         NoteProperty int one=1
two         NoteProperty int two=2
```

However, note that **just like all `[pscustomobject]` instances with type name `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` are treated the same even with differing properties, so are all the ones with `Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`**.
That is, `Select-Object`-created `[pscustomobject]` instances are also all treated the same, due to sharing the same, fixed type name.

---

<sup>[1] For instance, `1, 2, 3 | Get-Member` lists only *one* type, `System.Int32`, because all input objects have that type; by contrast, `1, 'foo', 2 | Get-Member` lists *two* types, `System.Int32` and `System.String` (but not `System.Int32` *again*).</sup>

<sup>[2] The ability to assign arbitrary type names is part of PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System) - see [about_types.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml)</sup>